# How to wrap into async the Cookies.get of my axios object

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

I have this axios object, and I have noticed that sometimes it fails to get accesstoken because of async issues.
How would you go about awaiting `Cookies.get('accesstoken')`

This is my code

```
  import axios from 'axios';
import constants from '../constants.js';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

    const API = axios.create({
      baseURL: `${constants.urlBackend}`,
      timeout: 10000,
      // headers: {
      //   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // },
    });



    API.interceptors.request.use(
      config => {
        var accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');

        if (accesstoken) {
          config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accesstoken}`;
        } else {
          delete API.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
        }
        return config;
      },

      error => Promise.reject(error)
    );

    export default API;
```

I dont think I can wrap the API.interceptos.request.use in an async function, or at least it didnt seem to work

Comment: Does the `Cookies.get()` function return a `Promise`?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier no

Comment: Then what is there to await? The issue probably lies elsewhere. *it fails to get accesstoken because of async issues*, but how do you know that?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier well thats what my testing has shown me. It always works, but maybe in 1/100 times, if you start reloading really fast a site with api calls, I receive the error of accesstoken being undefined. So I guess its because it doesnt have time to get it from the cookies

Comment: What if you set the `Authorization` header in the `axios.create` function instead of in the interceptor. What does that do?